# Loading data in table after I add a new task. reloadData()

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Can't load data in `UITableView`.

I've been building a to-do-list app. And in the end, can't load the table after adding a new task. It's adding but only shows when I rerun the app. How do I load the table and new added tasks? I use `viewDidAppear()` and `reloadData()` to make it work properly. But still not working

Here's my `FirstViewController`:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet var table: UITableView!

    var items: NSMutableArray = []

    //table view
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellContent = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        var cellLabel = ""

        if let tempLabel = items[indexPath.row] as? String{
            cellLabel = tempLabel
        }
        cellContent.textLabel?.text = cellLabel
        return cellContent

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool){

        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let itemsObject = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "items")

        if let tempItems = itemsObject as? NSMutableArray{

            items = tempItems
        }

            self.table.reloadData()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

**EDIT**

here's my code for the SecondViewController where I add new tasks.

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var taskValue: UITextField!

    @IBAction func addTask(_ sender: Any) {

        let itemsObject = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "items")

        var items:[String]

        if let tempItem = itemsObject as? [String] {

            items = tempItem

            items.append(taskValue.text!)
        } else{

            items = [taskValue.text!]

        }

        UserDefaults.standard.set(items, forKey: "items")

        taskValue.text = ""
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: please add..   self.table.delegate=self & self.table.dataSource=self

Comment: Did you check that all your if-let statements succeed?

Comment: @seggy I don't add anything like this ` self.table.delegate=self & self.table.dataSource=self`

Comment: Don't use `NSMutable...` collection types in Swift at all and there is a method `stringArray(forKey` to get a string array from `UserDefaults`. And where do you add new tasks?

Comment: please add & try

Comment: @seggy where do I add this? How can I declare it?

Comment: @Andreas Oetjen yeah they all work properly

Comment: @seggy Don't suggest to add delegate and datasource in code. Suggest to connect both in Interface Builder.

Comment: @vadian you are right but sometimes interface builder not work & i think he have to add in code

Comment: Can you show your "new task" codes? Where do you adding new task?

Comment: @vadian I've tried `stringArray(forKey)` method and instead of `NSMutab...` I put `[String]` as a simple array. But still doesn't work. Don't know what the problem is.

Comment: @IslamNurdin please copy from first comment and add into viewDidload() method

Comment: The question cannot be answered as long as the code to add new tasks is missing. And as you know that the data source array is an array of strings the line  `if let tempLabel ... as? String ` is nonsensical.

Comment: @IslamNurdin look at my answer

Comment: @vadian okay, I have added that code. Please check

Comment: @a.u.b I've added that code. Please check

Comment: It's alright to save your array in `UserDefaults` but it's not the right way to share data between controllers. Pass the new item back directly to the first view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Change the data source array to Swift array

  ```
  var items = [String]()
  ```
- in `viewDidAppear` use the correct API, if `stringArray(forKey` returns `nil` an empty array is assigned.

  ```
  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool){
     super.viewDidAppear(animated)
     items = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "items") ?? []
     self.table.reloadData()
   }
  ```
- Change `cellForRow` to this optimized version

  ```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cellContent = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

      let item = items[indexPath.row]
      cellContent.textLabel?.text = item
      return cellContent
  }
  ```

Note:

In Swift you get mutability for free just by assigning a value to a `var`iable. **Don't use the Foundation mutable collection types `NSMutableArray / NSMutableDictionary` at all. They are not related to the Swift counterparts.**

Answer (score 1):

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool){
     self.tableViewName.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking whether itemsObject is really NSMutableArray
in my simple example your case doesn't work

```
var items: NSMutableArray = ["]","{{"]
 UserDefaults.standard.set(items, forKey: "items")
        let itemsObject = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "items")

        if let tempItems = itemsObject as? NSMutableArray{

            items = tempItems // this line is not executed
        }
```

but

```
if let tempItems = itemsObject as? NSArray{

            // this block is used if you use NSArray instead of NSMutableArray

//here you can use this:
for object in tempItems {
                items.add(object)
            }
            }
```

works

Comment: Do I need to change items to `NSArray` ? or just cast `as? NSMutab...` ?

Comment: @IslamNurdin 1. I highly recommend using swift arrays instead of `NSArray` 2. To solve your issue I would suggest using loop inside `if let` statement

Comment: @IslamNurdin  None of them. Once again, don't use `NSArray / MSMutableArray` in Swift at all. You are fighting the strong type system. And optional downcast to `NSMutable...` collection types doesn't work anyway.

Comment: @Vyacheslav Okay. Using `NSArray` works for me but without a loop. Thanks

Comment: @vadian It also works when I replace `NSArray or NSMutab...` with simple array `[String]`.

Comment: @vadian I also use `stringArray(forkey)` method

Answer (score 0):

As per Apple documentation:

> Values returned from UserDefaults are immutable, even if you set a mutable object as the value. For example, if you set a mutable string as the value for “MyStringDefault”, the string you later retrieve using the string(forKey:) method will be immutable. If you set a mutable string as a default value and later mutate the string, the default value won’t reflect the mutated string value unless you call set(_:forKey:) again.

This means that this code never succeeds:

```
if let tempItems = itemsObject as? NSMutableArray{

    items = tempItems // this line is not executed
}
```

Since `UserDefaults` always returns immutable objects, you must change your code to:

```
if let tempItems = itemsObject as? NSArray{

    items = tempItems // this line is executed
}
```

You can still store `NSMutableArray` to the `UserDefaults` store, but on retrieving the data you must check for an immutable type.

As @vadian pointed out in the comments, you should instead use `stringArray` to retrieve the array object from `UserDefault`:

`UserDefaults.standard.stringArray("MyStringArray")`

[Apple docs - UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults)

Comment: The entire line `if let tempItems = itemsObject as? NSMutableArray{` is pointless if the OP uses the dedicated method `stringArray(forKey`

Comment: PS: The documentation is misleading. It is related to Objective-C. In Swift you get a mutable object simply with `var`.

Comment: I understand that's the case when using `stringArray(forKey)`, but is this also the case when using `object(forKey)` ?

Comment: Yes it is. Property list types are value types in Swift. You get a copy of the object anyway.